# Use "id" column instead of "_id" in CursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I'm overriding the CursorAdapter class, and got exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist" because primary key in my table is "id", not "_id".

I don't want to change it (database is not created on device, it's provided with app and copied from assets to /data/data/... directory).

Is it possible to make CursorAdapter use "id" field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to make CursorAdapter use "id" field?

No, but you can use `SELECT id AS _id, ...` to rename it. What it is named in the database is immaterial — what matters is what it is named in the `Cursor`.